# Pure HTML/CSS Drop Down Menu Closes When Clicking a Link (Link doesn't open)

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am trying to learn web development and I'm developing a layout for one of my sites.

I have followed a tutorial on building ad drop down menu with HTML and CSS only because I haven't really got into JS yet, and it's working fine except for one problem.

When I click a link in the drop down menu, it closes the drop down (Which is fine) but it doesn't travel to the new page. Here is my page and code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Rich Producer | Rich Sound</title>
        <meta name="Keywords" content="How to make beats, hip hop music production, rap music production, trap music production, download drum kits, download trap drums, massive presets, massive sound bank, trap sample pack, music production tutorials">
        <meta name="Description" content="Only the best drum kits, loop packages, massive presets, tutorials, and more for hip hop and trap music producers.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body-background">
            <nav class="container" id="nav">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-12 no-pad">
                        <a href="index.html" id="logolink"><div id="logo"><h1>Rich Producer</h1><h5 id="slogan">When Only the Best Will Do. . .</h5></div></a>

                            <ul id="navlist" class="nav">
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a href="#"> Drum Kits </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-container">
                                        <div class="dropdown-inner">
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                                                    <a href="#">808 &amp; Trap Kits</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div><!-- END DROP INNER -->
                                    </div><!-- END DROP CONTAINER -->
                                </li>

                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a href="#"> Presets &amp; Loops </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-container">
                                        <div class="dropdown-inner">
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                                                    <a href="#">Ni Massive Presets</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                                                    <a href="#">Loop Packs</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div><!-- END DROP INNER -->
                                    </div><!-- END DROP CONTAINER -->               
                                </li>

                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a href="#"> Motivation </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-container">
                                        <div class="dropdown-inner">
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                                                    <a href="beat-making-videos.html">Beat Making Videos</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                                                    <a href="#">Producer Interviews</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                                                    <a href="#">Music Production Tutorials</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div><!-- END DROP INNER -->
                                    </div><!-- END DROP CONTAINER -->
                                </li>

                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>

                            </ul>
                    </div><!--END NAVCOLUMN -->


                </div><!-- END ROW 1 (NAVIGATION) -->
            </nav>

            <div class="container content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Music Production Drum Kits, Synth Presets, Sound Packs, Tutorials and More!</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="mainpagepitch">From sounds to video tutorials, to the best producers making beats, Rich Producer has it all.<br>

                            Did we mention that we only post the best stuff?<br> That way you don't have to search through junk sounds and videos.<br>

                            Take a look around the site and find out more.<br>

                            With our help, you don't have to be a rich producer to sound like one.<br>
                        </p><hr>                
                    </div><!-- END COLUMN 1 of ROW 2 (Main Content)-->

                    <div class="col-4">
                        <h3 class="text-center">No spam - Ever!</h3>

                        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
                        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                            <form action="//learncalculusfree.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=56d231ceb905ccf52ff5b6d5b&amp;id=b623db0c1c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Enter your email and Rich Producer will send you:                            
                                    </label><br>

                                        <img src="img/LoudPackCover-thumb.png" alt="50 Free Massive Patches and Massive Presets" class="img-responsive img-center">

                                        <ul id="signup-list" class="text-center">
                                                <li>-50 Free Massive Presets (delivered instantly) </li> 
                                                <li>-In depth, high quality tutorials and beat breakdowns </li>
                                                <li>-Free drum kits so hot they'll burn your finger tips! </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
                                            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                                            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_56d231ceb905ccf52ff5b6d5b_b623db0c1c" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                                            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                                        </div><!-- END CENTER FOR BUTTON AND INPUT -->
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div><!--End mc_embed_signup-->
                    </div><!-- end signup column -->
                </div><!--END ROW 2 (CONTENT) -->








            </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
        </div><!--END BODY-BACKGROUND -->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body{
    /*smin-height: 900px;*/
}

#body-background{
    background-image: url("../img/studiobg.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    min-height: 1916px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);

}
/* PUSHES CONTENT DOWN TO MAKE GAP FROM NAV BAR */
.content{
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}

.row::before, .row::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    width: 8.33%;
    /*-- our gutter --*/
        padding: 12px;
}

.no-pad{
    padding: 0px;
}

.col-1{width: 8.33%;}

.col-2{ width: 16.66%;}

.col-3{ width: 21.99%;}

.col-4{ width: 33.32%;}

.col-5{ width: 41.65%;}

.col-6{ width: 49.98%;}

.col-7{ width: 58.31%;}

.col-8{ width: 66.64%;}

.col-9{ width: 74.97%;}

.col-10{width: 83.3%;}

.col-11{width: 91.63%;}

.col-12{width: 100%;}

.container *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px){
    .col-1{ width: 16.66%;}
    .col-2{ width: 33.32%;}
    .col-3{ width: 66.64%;}
    .col-4{ width: 100%;}
    .col-5{ width: 100%;}
    .col-6{ width: 100%;}
    .col-7{ width: 100%;}
    .col-8{ width: 100%;}
    .col-9{ width: 100%;}
    .col-10{ width: 100%;}
    .col-11{ width: 100%;}
    .col-12{ width: 100%;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 650px){
.col-1{width: 50%;}
.col-2{width: 100%;}
.col-3{width: 100%;}
.col-4{width: 100%;}
.col-5{width: 100%;}
.col-6{width: 100%;}
.col-7{width: 100%;}
.col-8{width: 100%;}
.col-9{width: 100%;}
.col-10{width: 100%;}
.col-11{width: 100%;}
.col-12{width: 100%;}
}

/************
STLYE NAVIGATION LOGO 
************/


div#logo{
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
}

#logolink{
    font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px;

}

#slogan{
    font-size: .8em;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light Two', cursive;
}
/************
START NAV LINK GROUP
*************/

#navlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

#navlist>li{
    float: left;
}

#navlist li a{
    display: block;
    color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

/* Sets active link color to #111 (black)        */
.active{
    background-color: #111;
}

/* DROP STYLING */

.dropdown-container{
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333;
}

ul.dropdown-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li a{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

.dropdown a:focus{
    background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown a:focus ~ .dropdown-container{
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
    -mox-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*END NAV STYLING*/

.mainpagepitch{
    line-height: 200%;
}

#signup-list{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 170%;
}

#signup-list li{
    margin-left: 8px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, label{
    color: #333;
}

/****************
RESPONSIVE IMG
****************/

.img-responsive{
    max-width: 100%
    height: auto;
}

.img-center{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy0cmkmt/

** Currently I only linked to a page under Motivation > Beat Making Videos, but I think you'll be able to tell it's not even trying to open the  links.

Comment: *** SOLUTION ***

Instead of doing on click I'm doing on hover. I will probably learn JS and change it later. 

I changed the max-height: 0px; to display: none; 

And then I made some changes to the last bit of css in the nav section. Here are those changes :

    .dropdown a:hover + .dropdown-container, .dropdown-container:hover{
 display: block;

 transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
 -mox-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't work because the moment you press the mouse, it trigger a `onmousedown` event, which unfocus the "motivation" `<a>` tag, making the dropdown menu collapse, hiding the desired link. The link only work if you can complete a mousedown *and* a mouseup event (combined into the mousepress event) on it.

In short, pure CSS drop down menu on click is not possible. I would suggest trying out :hover menu.

Comment: so you suggest that I change :focus to :hover?

I got it to work by chaging from max-height: 0  to display: none

and changing the last css to 

    .dropdown a:hover + .dropdown-container, .dropdown-container:hover{
 display: block;

 transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
 -mox-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}